# Openin exe binary files and editing

Tags: python, file-io, binary, exe

I'm working on a project to automatize a process. My task is to open an .exe file and edit the binary. I was researching for a possible solution to this task without any success. Does anyone know if there is a Python library or java class that can help? Or any other solution to edit an exe file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need to edit the binary data contained in the file, then it is just a matter of opening the file as binary and seeking/reading/writing as you would any other binary file.

See the Python docs about reading and writing files: [Reading and Writing Files](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

You'll do something like:

```
f = open('filename.exe', 'r+b') //'r+b' means read and write binary
```

Then proceed to seek through the file, read and write where needed.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your needs, you could treat the *.exe* file as an "ordinary" binary file as suggested in an other answer.

In other hand, if you need to "decode" Windows [*portable executable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) files (accessing header, copying sections), there are some dedicated Python module specialized in that task. I don't know which work the best or has the most features, but you should take a look for example to:

- [pefile](http://code.google.com/p/pefile/)
- [PELP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pelp/)